# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined for Air Quality API

Tags: javascript

I'm using an air quality index API to get the air quality once a user searches for a city, here is the relevant code to the error I'm getting:

```
function retrieveAirQuality(topResultUrl) {
    var airQualityAPIUrl = "http://api.waqi.info/feed/"+topResultUrl+"/?token="+airQualityAPIToken;

    fetch(airQualityAPIUrl)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        if(data.status === "ok") {
            // Saves air quality results to variable
            var airQualityResult = {
                aqi: data.data.aqi,
                name: data.data.city.name,
                iaqi: data.data.iaqi,
                date: data.data.time
            }

            renderAirQuality(airQualityResult);
        }
    })
}

function renderAirQuality(airQuality) {
    stationNameEl.textContent = "Station Name: " + airQuality.name + " on " + airQuality.date.s;

    var aqi = document.createElement("tr");
    aqi.innerHTML = "<th>Air Quality Index</th><td>"+airQuality.aqi+"</td>"
    airQualityTableCellEl.appendChild(aqi);

    var humidity = document.createElement("tr");
    humidity.innerHTML = "<th>Humidity</th><td>"+airQuality.iaqi.h.v+"</td>"
    airQualityTableCellEl.appendChild(humidity);

    var oz = document.createElement("tr");
    oz.innerHTML = "<th>Ozone</th><td>"+airQuality.iaqi.o3.v+"</td>" //Error here
    airQualityTableCellEl.appendChild(oz);

    var pressure = document.createElement("tr");
    pressure.innerHTML = "<th>Atmospheric Pressure</th><td>"+airQuality.iaqi.p.v+"</td>"
    airQualityTableCellEl.appendChild(pressure);

    var pm25 = document.createElement("tr");
    pm25.innerHTML = "<th>PM2.5</th><td>"+airQuality.iaqi.pm25.v+"</td>"
    airQualityTableCellEl.appendChild(pm25);

    var co = document.createElement("tr");
    co.innerHTML = "<th>Carbon Monoxide</th><td>"+airQuality.iaqi.co.v+"</td>"
    airQualityTableCellEl.appendChild(co);
}
```

The issue is, there are some cities that do not have all the variables that I am trying to add to my website. For example, there are many cities that do not have ozone levels available from the API so I would get the "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'v')" error in the line stated above. Not sure how to fix this

Comment: `+(airQuality.iaqi.o3?.v ?? "N/A")+`

Comment: Do you know how to use `if`?

Comment: @JaromandaX Worked, thank you! I'm new to JavaScript so if you don't mind I would love for you to explain how the "?" and the "??" operators work? Thanks though!

Comment: @robertklep I did try using an if statement like if(variable) or if(variable !== "undefined") but those didn't work

Comment: Use hasOwnProperty() it is best way instead of using if cases. Or add try cache block

Comment: `?` is the ternary operator, but that's irrelevant ... `?.` = optional chaining and `??` = nullish coalescing - both documented on MDN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different solutions to this problem:

If you want to keep a tr with an empty `td`, then use this :

```
var oz = document.createElement("tr");  
oz.innerHTML = "<th>Ozone</th><td>"+airQuality?.iaqi?.o3?.v+"</td>";  
airQualityTableCellEl.appendChild(oz);
```

And if you don't want to add `tr` at all if the parameter is not present, then do something like this:

```
var oz = document.createElement("tr");
oz.innerHTML = "<th>Ozone</th><td>"+airQuality?.iaqi?.o3?.v+"</td>";
(airQuality?.iaqi?.o3?.v) && airQualityTableCellEl.appendChild(oz);
```

even you can implement the second one with `if` condition like this : `if(airQuality?.iaqi?.o3?.v)`

Hope this helps!

Comment: IMO, using `if` in the second example makes the code a lot more readable.